# Accessing public folder from microsoft EWS using Viewpoint in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, exchangewebservices

Trying to use the [viewpoint gem](https://github.com/WinRb/Viewpoint) to access my contacts in a public folder of my EWS.

Using viewpoint though, it seems like I only have access to my personal folders such as index, contacts, calendar, trash... But none of the public folders show up.

Any help on this subject would be great. Or if there is another gem out there that may suit me better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I got it figured out after having the same issue and keep on googling.

In your model method where you get the folder from EWS you can get the public folder like this:

`contacts = client.get_folder_by_name "name of your folder", parent: :publicfoldersroot`